# Intellij 15 CE set Tab Size

Tags: intellij-idea

Can someone tell me hoe I can set the tabs to spaces and the size of them in the new version IntelliJ version 15?

I can't seem to find it. There are options but it is language specific (Java/Groovy etc etc)

Answer (score 0):

For a current file you can go to `Edit` -> `Convert Indents` then in your case `To Spaces`. For sizing you'll need to set it dependant on language.

*side note*: [EditorConfig](http://editorconfig.org/) is something worth looking at for managing coding styles, which already comes with Intellij Idea 15.

Comment: @TrtTrt It's enabled by default, you can see how to create one quickly here: https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/configuring-code-style.html#editorconfig